# DirectShow code crashes after exit (PushSourceDesktop sample)

Tags: c++, com, directshow

I'm trying to use the Desktop capture filter that comes with the SDK (PushSourceDesktop). I compiled it and seem to use it successfully as it actually captures my desktop and saves it to a file. But the application crashes when its done/exits.

When I break on the error it only says no source available and the call stack location is KernelBase.dll!7560280C().

I thought I give it a shot here to see if anyone can recognize some issue or if I am doing something blatantly wrong that might cause the crash. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: working code

```
int main()
{

HRESULT hr;

hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
{
CComPtr<IBaseFilter> pMux;
CComPtr<IMediaControl> pMC;
CComPtr<IBaseFilter> pFilterr;
CComPtr<IGraphBuilder> pGraph;
CComPtr<ICaptureGraphBuilder2> pBuild;
CComPtr<IUnknown> pUnk;

hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CaptureGraphBuilder2, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IID_ICaptureGraphBuilder2, (void**)&pBuild);


hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void**)(&pGraph));

hr = pBuild->SetFiltergraph(pGraph);


static CLSID const clsid = {0x4ea6930a, 0x2c8a, 0x4ae6, {0xa5, 0x61, 0x56, 0xe4, 0xb5, 0x4, 0x44, 0x37}}; //Pushsourcedesktop

 hr = CreateObjectFromPath(TEXT("c:\\filters\\PushSource.dll"), clsid, &pUnk);

 pFilterr = pUnk;

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    HRESULT hr = pGraph->AddFilter(pFilterr, L"Private Filter");
}

hr = pBuild->SetOutputFileName(
    &MEDIASUBTYPE_Avi,  // Specifies AVI for the target file.
    L"C:\\wav\\Example2.avi", // File name.
    (IBaseFilter**)&pMux,              // Receives a pointer to the mux.
    NULL); 


hr = pBuild->RenderStream(
    NULL,//PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE,//NULL,//&PIN_CATEGORY_CAPTURE, // Pin category.
    NULL,//&MEDIATYPE_Video,//&MEDIATYPE_Interleaved,//NULL,//&MEDIATYPE_Audio,      // Media type.
    pFilterr,//pSrc,           // Capture filter.
   NULL,//pCompression2, //pCompression,                  // Intermediate filter (optional).
    (IBaseFilter*)pMux);                 // Mux or file sink filter.


    hr = pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_IMediaControl, (void **)&pMC);
    printf("START");  


    pMC->Pause();
    hr = pMC->Run();
    Sleep(4000);
      hr = pMC->Stop();
    printf("END");  

}
CoUninitialize();
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *big* problem is that you have to call `CoUninitialize` only after all COM pointers are released. Now that you are using raw pointers instead of `CComPtr`-like smart templates, your code both is poorly readable, and it is so easy to make a mistake and forget to release one of the pointers. `CoUninitialize` cleans things up and then later on it appears that some COM object is still alive and it quickly gets into trouble and crashes your app.

Additionally to this, I don't see a reason for you to use `COINIT_MULTITHREADED` apartment. To stay away of trouble, you should rather do all top-level management on filter graphs from STA thread. Streaming and worker threads will be MTA, and it is fine.

`ATL` offers [`CComPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezzw7k98.aspx) templates well described on MSDN. DirectShow BaseClasses offer you a lightweight analog `QzCComPtr` which I suggest you start using for your own convenience.

Your code will look like this:

```
CoInitialize(...);
{
  CComPtr<IFooA> pFooA;
  CComPtr<IFooB> pFooB;
  // ...
}
CoUninitialize();
```

The idea is that all `~CComPtr` are done before code reaches `CoUninitialize`.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now, I added the change to the code. Thank you for clarifying that vital point!