# Unreleased DirectShow CSource filter makes program crash at process shutdown

Tags: com, directshow

I'm developing a DirectShow CSource capture filter. It works fine, but when I close the program that is using the filter (in this case I'm testing with VLC, but the same happens with other programs), the program crashes (if I'm debugging it in Visual Studio then a breakpoint is triggered).

I've been hunting down this problem for some time now and found that both, my source filter and my source stream are not being released; this is, their reference counter is 1 at the end of the program, DllCanUnloadNow() function reports that there are 2 objects still in use, and, when CoUninitialize() is invoked, the program crashes.

I'm pretty sure that the reference counters are being handled correctly since I'm using the base classes implementation. The only unusual thing in my software that I can think of is that I'm using my own version of DllGetClassObject(): I configured the .DEF file to have MyDllGetClassObject() exported instead of DllGetClassObject() so I could insert some code before invoking the default implementation. I don't think this is a problem since I've checked that the reference counter of all objects I return at the end of MyDllGetClassObject() is 1.

I guess I'm missing something about the lifecycle of the filter, but can't figure out what (this is the very first capture filter I'm developing). Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance,

Guillermo

Comment: Do you have a stack trace at the time of crash/exception?

Comment: The stack trace doesn't contain any of my functions:  
    KernelBase.dll!76c7280c()
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for KernelBase.dll]
    MyFilters.dll!DbgAssert(const wchar_t *pCondition=0x00540052, const wchar_t * pFileName=0x00460020, int iLine=0x00690061) Line 557 + 0x8 bytes C++
    00450053()

Comment: `MyFilters.dll` is not your code? It's `DbgAssert` suggests it is a debug build.

Comment: `MyFilters.dll` contains my code but `DbgAssert` is part of the base classes. This is a debug build, but the same happens in release builds too.

I've set a breakpoint before the `DebugBreak` and the error raised during a call to `_DllEntryPoint` (invoked by `DllEntryPoint`).

`_DllEntryPoint` is full of messages complaining about `MyFilters.dll` holding two living objects. I believe I'm not releasing my objects where I'm supposed to do it. Do I have to release filters returned by `MyDllGetClassObject` and `IClassFactory` (both of which are implemented by me)? If yes, where should I do it?

Comment: `DbgAssert` indicates that you have a problem in your DLL. It is something with incorrect manipulation with COM pointers and references. You have not yet given any information to tell what exactly is wrong. It is up to you to debug, see what items are unreleased, what could have been the reason.

Comment: The problem is that there are two COM objects (the source filter and the source stream) that have not been released by the time the process is shutdown. Those objects were created in a custom implementation of `IClassFactory`, which is invoked by `MyDllGetClassObject`. I'm not explicitly invoking `Release` on any of those COM objects, as I expect the client to do so. I think I should be releasing those COM objects myself, but I don't know which part of my code should do that. Do you know, from the filter implmentation point of view, when should I be releasing filters I create?

Comment: When factory creates an instance, it returns it to the caller with reference counter of `1`. From there on it is a life of COM object alone, once caller does not need interfaces anymore it does `IUnknown::Release` and when counter reaches zero then destruction takes place. As a filter developer you are interested it making sure it takes place. Factory does not track created filters and it not expected to free them.

Comment: Reference counter for objects I return from my factory is `1`. I agree in having my filter properly destroyed on time. But the fact is that it is not being destroyed because the reference counter sits at `1` at process shutdown. Just one `IUnknown::Release` more is required, but the client won't invoke it. That's why I think that I myself should be releasing that remaining reference from the implementation side. My question is _where_ should I do that. Anyway, supposing that the client is faulty, do you know how can I release objects I created instead of letting the process crash? Thanks.

Comment: Now you are going to release it. Then what about the real holder of this reference, what if he would release its own?

Comment: Well... the fact is that the owner is not taking care of it. So I wonder whether the owner it's me... Hence my question: do I have to release an object I return from my `IClassFactory` at any point in time? If yes, when and where? If no, why would a DirectShow application that is known to work with other filters fail when it comes to release my filters? Thanks.

Comment: `1` No. `2` Probably because it works fine and the bug is still yours.

Comment: OK, that my software has a bug is something I already knew. I'll try to be more specific: since I'm not invoking `AddRef`, nor `Release` on my filter, can you think of a situation that would prevent the filter graph from releasing my filter? Thanks.

Comment: When filter graph is released, it is expected to release all filters. Without other outstanding references filter are destroyed. If this does not happen, it is likely to be a bug. You might want to compensate for this missing/leaking `Release` if you want, but it is already a risky patch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on. The static method `InitializeInstance` in my source filter is invoked with `bLoading == false` and `rclsid == <the GUID of my filter>` at process shutdown. That seems to be the appropriate place to release that remaining reference counter from the filter instance.

I got the key idea of how important is to release all COM objects before `CoUninitialize` some time ago from another post on StackOverflow entitled [DirectShow code crashes after exit (PushSourceDesktop sample)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249298/directshow-code-crashes-after-exit-pushsourcedesktop-sample). All I needed was just a little bit more knowledge on DirectShow filters lifecycle.

Anyway, thank you for your efforts, Roman, I know how vague this thread sounded from the beginning :)