# Not releasing filter com object causing a crash

Tags: c++, video, com, directshow

I am using Viveks capture filter with vlc (http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads/vcam.zip) to emulate a capture source. When the filter is open and I close vlc I get a crash. The stack trace indicates that 2 COM objects still exist (Im guessing the filter and pin) which should be released before a CoUninitialize call. My problem is I am not sure where to release the filter and pin COM objects, I have a destructor for the fitler and pin but they are never called when vlc closes. Someone who had a similar problem ([Unreleased DirectShow CSource filter makes program crash at process shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295434/unreleased-directshow-csource-filter-makes-program-crash-at-process-shutdown)).

This is the important registering part of the dll.

```
STDAPI RegisterFilters( BOOL bRegister )
{
    HRESULT hr = NOERROR;
    WCHAR achFileName[MAX_PATH];
    char achTemp[MAX_PATH];
    ASSERT(g_hInst != 0);

    if( 0 == GetModuleFileNameA(g_hInst, achTemp, sizeof(achTemp))) 
        return AmHresultFromWin32(GetLastError());

    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0L, achTemp, lstrlenA(achTemp) + 1, 
                   achFileName, NUMELMS(achFileName));

    hr = CoInitialize(0);
    if(bRegister)
    {
        hr = AMovieSetupRegisterServer(CLSID_VirtualCam, L"Virtual Cam", achFileName, L"Both", L"InprocServer32");
    }

    if( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
    {
        IFilterMapper2 *fm = 0;

        hr = CreateComObject( CLSID_FilterMapper2, IID_IFilterMapper2, fm );
        if( SUCCEEDED(hr) )
        {
            if(bRegister)
            {
                IMoniker *pMoniker = 0;
                REGFILTER2 rf2;
                rf2.dwVersion = 1;
                rf2.dwMerit = MERIT_DO_NOT_USE;
                rf2.cPins = 1;
                rf2.rgPins = &AMSPinVCam;
                hr = fm->RegisterFilter(CLSID_VirtualCam, L"Virtual Cam", &pMoniker, &CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, NULL, &rf2);
            }
            else
            {
                hr = fm->UnregisterFilter(&CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, 0, CLSID_VirtualCam);
            }
        }  

      // release interface
      //
      if(fm)
          fm->Release();
    }

    if( SUCCEEDED(hr) && !bRegister )
         hr = AMovieSetupUnregisterServer( CLSID_VirtualCam );

    CoFreeUnusedLibraries();
    CoUninitialize();
    return hr;
}

STDAPI DllRegisterServer()
{
    return RegisterFilters(TRUE);
}

STDAPI DllUnregisterServer()
{
    return RegisterFilters(FALSE);
}

extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllEntryPoint(HINSTANCE, ULONG, LPVOID);

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HANDLE hModule, DWORD  dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    return DllEntryPoint((HINSTANCE)(hModule), dwReason, lpReserved);
}
```

The important filter part

```
CVCamStream::CVCamStream(HRESULT *phr, CVCam *pParent, LPCWSTR pPinName) :
CSourceStream(NAME("Virtual Cam"),phr, pParent, pPinName), m_pParent(pParent)
{
    // Set the default media type as 320x240x24@15
    GetMediaType(4, &m_mt);
}

CVCamStream::~CVCamStream()
{
    m_pParent->Release();
}
```

Comment: Please provide a small code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Leaked COM references are a sort of hard to nail down. Assuming that COM client - in your case VLC - is doing everything right (which might be not the case, but it's okay to start with this assumption), the problem is on your code. It is typically one of the two:

1. You are dealing with raw pointers and there is somewhere no matching `Release` for `AddRef` done earlier
2. There are circular references and object keep each other alive

As you already see you have two objects floating around, a good strategy would be to identify what classes are they exactly, and trace reference counter changes to see where is the lost `IUnknown::Release`.

Comment: I am using raw pointers, I heard about using CComPtr but wasnt able to get them in my visual studio version. Do you know how I can monitor the reference count to objects?

Comment: Also I think vlc is doing stuff correctly as I can open a decklink capture source and close it without any error.

Comment: Put debug output tracing in: constructors, destructors, AddRef, Release methods. Check the log to get a clue. It is easy to make a mistake with raw pointers - this is where `CComPtr` come to help (`QzCComPtr` is the alternate copy in DirectShow BaseClasses for those who have no ATL, or otherwise don't want to use it).

Comment: Would QzCComPtr pointers call release when there is a crash or they go out of scope?

Comment: These classes are just a few screens of code, you can just look at it and you will get the idea. Leaving scope crashing, destructors (and hence, Release) might be called or might be not depending on compiler settings, exception handling in particular.

Comment: Seems like its on VLC's side, the same problem does not occur in graphstudionext, the decklink graph could work cause it might have not been built with the same debug mode that im using.