# CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream let my thread hangs

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, com

```
UINT __stdcall CExternal::WorkThread( void * pParam)
{
    HRESULT hr;
    CTaskBase* pTask;
    CComPtr<IHTMLDocument3> spDoc3;
    CExternal* pThis = reinterpret_cast<CExternal*>(pParam);

    if (pThis == NULL)
        return 0;

    // Init the com
    ::CoInitializeEx(0,COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    hr = ::CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(
        pThis->m_pStream_,
        IID_IHTMLDocument3,
        (void**)&spDoc3);

    if(FAILED(hr))
        return 0;

    while (pThis->m_bShutdown_ == 0) 
    {
        if(pThis->m_TaskList_.size()) 
        {
            pTask = pThis->m_TaskList_.front();
            pThis->m_TaskList_.pop_front();

            if(pTask) 
            {
                pTask->doTask(spDoc3); //do my custom task
                delete pTask;
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            Sleep(10);
        }
    }

    OutputDebugString(L"start CoUninitialize\n");
    ::CoUninitialize(); //release com
    OutputDebugString(L"end CoUninitialize\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The above the code that let my thread hang, the only output is "start `CoUninitialize`".

```
m_hWorker_ = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, WorkThread, this, 0, 0);
```

This code starts my thread, but the thread can't exit safely, so it waits. What the problem with this code?

Comment: As Hans explained in detail, you need a) to release `spDoc3` before calling `CoUninitialize`, and b) if the hosting apartment for the COM object is STA (which is likely), it should be pumping messages at the time of worker thread termination. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11249540/868014

Comment: thanks for your answer ,but spDoc3.Release() was hang when i try to release it.

    spDoc3.Release();

Comment: All right then, so you have the other condition of the two to meet (".... you'll get deadlock when the owner thread of a single-threaded object (like a browser) is not pumping.").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in this code, although it violates core COM requirements.  Which says that you should release interface pointers when you no longer use them, calling IUnknown::Release(), and that an apartment-threaded thread must pump a message loop.  Especially the message loop is important, you'll get deadlock when the owner thread of a single-threaded object (like a browser) is not pumping.

CoUninitialize() is forced to clean up the interface pointer wrapped by spDoc3 since you didn't do this yourself.  It is clear from the code that the owner of the interface pointer actually runs on another thread, something to generally keep in mind since that pretty much defeats the point of starting your own worker thread.  Creating your own STA thread doesn't fix this, it is still the wrong thread.

So the proxy needs to context switch to the apartment that owns the browser object.  With the hard requirement that this apartment pumps a message loop so that the call can be dispatched on the right thread in order to safely call the Release() function.  With very high odds that this thread isn't pumping messages anymore when your program is shutting down.  Something you should be able to see in the debugger, locate the owner thread in the Debug + Windows + Threads window and see what it is doing.

Deadlock is the common outcome.  The only good way to fix it is to shut down threads in the right order, this one has to shut down before the thread that owns the browser object.  Shutting down a multi-threaded program cleanly can be quite difficult when threads have an interdependency like this.  The inspiration behind the C++11 std::quick_exit() addition.

Comment: i think i can't to fix it,the code is very simple and i can't find what's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for all the people,use MsgWaitForMultipleObjects instead of WaitForSingleObject can solve it,the reason is that WaitForSingleObject block the message loop.